# Export to Excel - detail in one row - subreport in a cell

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, subreport

I'm using *JasperReports* for a generating report in *Excel* format.

My report has one detail line. This line includes a subreport (database relation 1:N).

The generated *Excel* file has several rows for every line from master report (*Detail* band) - one row for each subreport's line.

I need one row in *Excel* file for each report's line (row in *Detail* band), also each subreport in a cell not in a new line.

How I can do it?

My template:

[image]

Comment: In other words, you want to put some information from several fields (subreport's fields) in one cell, right? Can you post the screenshot of your target report's design?

Comment: yes, exactly. i have a part of my report as screenshot uploded.

Comment: IMHO, it is impossible without at least deep customizing of implementation Excel exporter (*JRXlsExporter* class)

Comment: can i use a alternative possibility?

Comment: BTW, you can look at [iReport: How to group several same value field into a single cell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9798399/876298) post