# iReport Cell Spanning in Table Component

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, xmltable

I'm using the iReport with to display data from a `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRTableModelDataSource` in a table. I'm using the TableModelDataSource, because I have to use Java as a data source.

I now got the following code, which is working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="controltest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.3310000000000022"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="276"/>
    <property name="ireport.callouts" value="##Wed Dec 05 08:22:05 CET 2012"/>
    <subDataset name="plantsResultTable">
        <field name="COLUMN_0" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="COLUMN_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="COLUMN_2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="COLUMN_3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="COLUMN_4" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="COLUMN_5" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="readActualSupply" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <group name="supplyGroup">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{readActualSupply}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <field name="remotelyControlledSupply" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="thirdPartyAccess" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="plantsResultTable" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="675">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="250" width="555" height="239"/>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement key="table 2" x="0" y="17" width="555" height="222"/>
                    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="plantsResultTable">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{plantsResultTable}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:column width="90">
                            <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[COLUMN_0]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </jr:columnHeader>
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField pattern="">
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20">
                                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{supplyGroup_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                                    </reportElement>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_0}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="90">
                            <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[COLUMN_1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </jr:columnHeader>
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="90">
                            <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[COLUMN_2]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </jr:columnHeader>
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="90">
                            <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[COLUMN_3]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </jr:columnHeader>
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="90">
                            <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[COLUMN_4]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </jr:columnHeader>
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="90">
                            <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[COLUMN_5]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </jr:columnHeader>
                            <jr:detailCell height="20">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                    <textElement/>
                                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_5}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                    </jr:table>
                </componentElement>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

What I need to know now is

1. Is there a way to center the COLUMN_0 value vertically (set vertical alignment to "center"). I guess it's got to go by sth like `if $V{supplyGroup_COUNT} == $V{supplyGroup_SIZE}/2`. I have the table shown under "actual", but I want it dynamically to look like "target".
   [image: vertical align]
2. Is there a way to print another COLUMN_0 value if the table has a page break. That is the table begins on page 1 and breaks onto page 2 ending there. Can I print a COLUMN_0 value on page 1 and on page 2? I put an `<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{supplyGroup_COUNT} == 1 || $P{hasPageBreak}.equals("1"))]]></printWhenExpression>` to my table's textField, but the compiler complains about not being able to find the parameter hasPageBreak. At the moment I just count the items in my table and put another "text" visible if $V{supplyGroup_COUNT} == 20 and if there is a new page.

[image: repeat value after break]
 3. Is there a way to force a table to break after a certain amount of items? I have some text that follows the table. I'd like to always have at least a part (the end) of the table together with the following text. Or do I have to use two separate tables?

[image: breaking table]

Comment: `Is there a way to center the COLUMN_0 value` - What do you mean?

Comment: @AlexK I edited my post. I meant the vertical alignment of the COLUMN_0 value. In your solution for user1264222's question you used the expression `$V{supplyGroup_COUNT} == 1` so the value is written in the first cell. I'd like to display it in the center.

Comment: In other words you want to apply style (vertical alignment) to the field in some cases (conditional style). Am I right?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, I added some images, to illustrate my question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you can vertically align table cell contents

```
<textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
```

I use a style

```
<style name="table_TD" vAlign="Middle" />
```

I'm not certain about the other two (contributions welcome)

2)  isReprintHeaderOnEachPage works for group headers but I'm not sure about for tables?
 (I often use a cut down subreport in place of a table.)

3) [Split Type](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/SplitTypeEnum.html) on the band may help but if "some text" is a separate object I don't believe you can stop it from being orphaned

Hope that helps